# Swift playgrounds UIButton not working correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I've got this UIButton called 'start button' in swift playgrounds. This is the setup for it.

```
    func setupStartButton() {
        startButton.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 550, width: 125, height: 50)
        startButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(ciColor: CIColor(red: 255/255, green: 0/255, blue: 77/255, alpha: 1.0))
        startButton.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        startButton.setTitle("Start", for: .normal)
        startButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        startButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(startButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(startButton)
```

I call this in viewDidLoad().

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 524, height: 766)
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        setupStartButton()

        PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
        PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
    }
```

But when I tap on a button it doesn't run the function called 'startButtonTapped' which just prints "Hello" to the console.

This is the function 'startButtonTapped'.

```
    @objc func startButtonTapped() {
        print("Hello")
    }
```

Why does it not do anything when I tap the button?
How can I fix this?
Thank you

Comment: It prints to console not screen.

Comment: I know but it's not printing to the console

Comment: show more of your code so people can repeat the situation. I tried with a blank template and adding your current code. Every thing is fine

Comment: you can try to change your startButtonTapped to `startButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton)`. Don't forget to change it in `startButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(startButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)` too

Comment: No it's still not working, I'm so confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see the rest of your code. I just quickly created one so that you could compare with your own code.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class VC: UIViewController {

    let startButton = UIButton(type: .system)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupStartButton()
    }

    func setupStartButton() {
        startButton.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 550, width: 125, height: 50)
        startButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(ciColor: CIColor(red: 255/255, green: 0/255, blue: 77/255, alpha: 1.0))
        startButton.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        startButton.setTitle("Start", for: .normal)
        startButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        startButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(startButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(startButton)
    }

    @objc func startButtonTapped() {
        print("Hello")
    }
}

let vc = VC()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah it's working now, before I didn't save the view controller class to a variable and then assign it to the live view. Thank you